# How do I recursively call a prototype function inside itself while looping an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm creating a polyfill of Array.flat() method, however, I'm facing issues while calling the function within itself after checking that the looped element is an array and thats need to be flattened further. When a write a code that is not prototypal, the flattening is proper, however when I try to create a prototype function, I'm unable to get the flattened array. I'm pretty sure that the issue is related with the 'this' keyword. Please have a look at my code.

Here is the code

```
let arrayFlat = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, [9]], 10, [11, 12]], [13, [14, 15]]];

const flatArray = (array) => {
  let output = [];
  const flatten = (array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
        flatten(array[i]);
      } else {
        output.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    return output;
  };
  return flatten(array);
};

Array.prototype.myFlat = function () {
  let output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(this[i])) {
      console.log(this[i]);
      this[i].myFlat();
    } else {
      output.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
```

Comment: @NicholasTower same with `flatten(array[i]);` in the first function.

Comment: Also the normal way to make a polyfill would be to do something like `Array.prototype.flat || function() { ...}`

Comment: The reason it's fine in the first example is that there's a single array `output` which all recursions are interacting with; all the code pushes to the same array. In the second, every recursion creates its own array. They push to their own array, but these arrays are never combined.

Comment: @NicholasTower, thanks for the reply. I agree that I'm doing nothing with flatten(array[i]) and this[i].myFlat(). In the flatten(array[i]), I'm actually returning the updated output array, however, in case of this[i].myFlat(), I'm confused as to what has to be done to update the output array. The flatten(array) is working fine, I have issue with the polyfill function

Comment: @NicholasTower, yes you are right, in the first case, the same output array is updated. So, how do I achieve the same thing in second case?

Comment: Having another function such as flattenArray() inside the prototype function is working fine. Just wanted to know, what is the scenario where we can recursively call a prototypal function within itself, instead of creating another function within the prototype and recursively calling the created function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first piece of code, you create a single `output` array. When you recursively call `flatten`, the code is always pushing to the exact same `output` array, which is in the closure of `flatten`. Then once everything is done, you return that array.

In the second code, you create a new array every time you recurse. Each recursion will create an array, flatten itself, and then return that new array. But the return value is ignored, so these values don't go anywhere.

You have a few options

1. Make the code basically identical to your first one, with an internal function for doing the recursion, and a closure variable used by all:

```
Array.prototype.myFlat = function () {
  let output = [];
  const flatten = (array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
        flatten(array[i]);
      } else {
        output.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    return output;
  };
  return flatten(this);
}
```

2. Pass the output array as a parameter when you recurse:

```
//                                 VVVVVV--- added parameter
Array.prototype.myFlat = function (output = []) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(this[i])) {
      this[i].myFlat(output); // <---- forward the array along
    } else {
      output.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
```

3. Continue having separate arrays, but then merge them together as the stack unwinds:

```
Array.prototype.myFlat = function () {
  let output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(this[i])) {
      output.push(...this[i].myFlat()); // <---- added output.push
    } else {
      output.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a strong proponent of keeping classes as thin as possible, wrapping functional interfaces wherever possible -

```js
function myFlat(t) {
  return Array.isArray(t)
    ? t.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(myFlat(v)), [])
    : [t]
}

Array.prototype.myFlat = function() { return myFlat(this) }

console.log([1,[2,[3],4],[[5]],6,[[[7]]]].myFlat())
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```